# Why can't heroku get the text files on my folder while running my program?

Tags: python, file, heroku, discord, discord.py

I am doing a simple discord bot with python and I'm using heroku to host it. I have some commands that return a big text, so I put these texts on separate .txt files and organized all those files in a single folder called "files". Then I used the code to access and read those files. Everything works fine when I am hosting the bot, but heroku always returns a "FileNotFoundError" when he is hosting.

The full error message:

```
Ignoring exception in command helpie:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/main.py", line 27, in helpie
helpmessage = open(".\files\helpMessage.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.\x0ciles\\helpMessage.txt'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.\x0ciles\\helpMessage.txt'
```

Here is one of the commands that use a .txt file. This code is on the main.py file, that heroku is reading.

```
@bot.command()
async def helpie(ctx):
    helpmessage = open(".\files\helpMessage.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8")
    await ctx.send(helpmessage.read())
    helpmessage.close()
```

Here is the tree of the root folder of the program and all it's files:

```
C:.
│   .gitignore
│   main.py
│   Procfile
│   README.md
│   requirements.txt
│   runtime.txt
│
├───.vscode
└───files
        bot icon.png
        geraldoMessage.txt
        helpMessage.txt
```

I don't know if it is necessary, but I will also include the content of the "requirements.txt" and "Procfile".

Procfile:

```
worker: python main.py
```

requirements.txt

```
discord.py
asyncio
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: have you tried using the absolute path of the file in heroku to feed to the `open()` statement? Also, the file you are trying to reach might have a different pathing, if heroku is using `/` as path separator.

Comment: I wouldn't use an absolute path, as that's almost certain to differ between environments (in particular between Heroku and what appears to be a local Windows machine). But I _would_ suggest making the path relative to a known location. Right now it's relative to whatever the working directory is.

Comment: What is the full error message? I suspect you're getting something like `No such file or directory: '.\x0ciles\\helpMessage.txt'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect a more complete error would be something like this:

```
No such file or directory: '.\x0ciles\\helpMessage.txt'
```

The immediate issue is probably that you're accidentally using an [escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) by including `\f` in your string, which indicates an ASCII form feed.

Note that the path has been mangled. You *could* us a raw string here:

```py
open(r".\files\helpMessage.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8")
#    ^ raw string
```

Or you could change how you define that path. Forward slashes are safer than backslashes, and joining individual path components together using `pathlib` or `os.path` is safer still.

I don't think this is your immediate issue, but your path is also relative to whatever the working directory happens to be. I suggest making it relative to a known location, e.g. the root directory of your project.

Putting that together, try something like this (using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib)):

```py
from pathlib import Path

# This will point to the right directory no matter what the working directory is
root_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


@bot.command()
async def helpie(ctx):
    helpmessage = open(root_path / "files" / "helpMessage.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8")
    #                            ^         ^ safely joining components
    #                  ^^^^^^^^^ known path
    await ctx.send(helpmessage.read())
    helpmessage.close()
```

or like this (using [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#module-os.path)):

```py
import os.path

root_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


@bot.command()
async def helpie(ctx):
    helpmessage = open(os.path.join(root_path, "files", "helpMessage.txt"), "r", encoding = "utf-8")
    #                               ^^^^^^^^^ known path
    #                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ safely joining components
    await ctx.send(helpmessage.read())
    helpmessage.close()
```